# how can I translate the meaning of a certain variable in the csv data file to be read in R using another dataframe as the dictionary?

Tags: dataframe, indexing, naming

I need to process my raw data. I would `R` to read the variable columns using another data frame as the dictionary.

For example, in one of my variable columns:

```
1 = Male
2 = Female
99 = no answer
```

I need to code in `R` so that when I input data of that variable, `R` then reads `1` as `Male` and so on. 
I have tried the merge and index functions.

Comment: Show the code you've tried so far

Comment: getwd()
list.files 
trial <- read.csv("~/SampleCSV.csv",header=TRUE)
names (trial)
trial$CYPHPASQ01
summary (trial)
cor(trial[c("CYPHPSCScore","CYPHPASScore")])
trial.sub0 <- subset (trial,select=c("CYPHPSCScore","CYPHPASScore"))
trial.sub3 <- subset (trial,select=c("CYPHPASQ01"))
library (plyr)
trial.sub3 <- factor(c("1","2","99"))
revalue(trial.sub3, c("1"="yes", "2"="no","99"= "noanswer"))

Comment: that code was previous to trying to use another file for the dictionary? (apologies I am v new to dis all!)

Comment: Don't place the code in comments, otherwise its readability is poor. Instead edit your question and place code there